# Why is finish() not quitting processing immediately? 

Tags: java, android, activity-finish

Is there any particular situation when it is handy to not quit the Activity immediately after calling `finish()` ?

(in other way, why is this method not quitting the Activity immediately from design?)

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

**UPDATE**

When I say immediately, I mean, right in time you will call the `finish()` and of course, cleaning up with saving instance bundle, onStop and onDestroy methods doesn't count.

To see an example what am I talking about, here is the snippet

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    // code executed
    if(somecondition){
        finish();
    }
    // code which shouldn't be executed
}
```

the question is, why is the code after condition finished as well before ending activity, and why the `finish()` call not stopping the processing immediately

Comment: What do you mean by immediately?

Comment: Its by design of course - `Activity` follows its life-cycle when you call `Activity#finish()`, pausing, stopping and destroying your activity - and unless you **clean up** after yourself you can still have junk in other threads running or stuff posting back to the UI-thread.

Comment: @Flo I mean immediately after calling this method, rest of code in current proccess block will be skipped

Comment: @Jens I understand this, please see update of my question, to see what am I talking about

Comment: Well, yes, but `finish()` isn't like `System#exit(int)` in normal Java - it only notifies Android that the current activity should wrap-up and exit - for it to do what you want it would have to throw an exception or kill the VM - both kind of unsavory and pointless things to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't you do a return to prevent the codes below to execute:

```
if(somecondition){
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Comment: good suggestion, I already do things like that. The question was about `why do we have to do it like this` not `how can we avoid executing rest of function code`. But thanks anyway

Comment: That's the nature of Java. You can only stop the execution by return, end of method block, or throwing exceptions.
If you want to avoid return, probably you can add the else block 
    if(somecondition){
        finish();
        } else {
    }

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a thread_0 with a loop handling all the events.

Calling finish adds a new event, but the activity isn't killed until thread_0 handles the event.

Comment: Ok, so you say, calling `finish()` is way how to flag your activity as `ready-to-be-killed/finished` and not triggering the finish code immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Something to check: are you running any Async tasks that are not finished?

Comment: no, any async task in time of calling `finish()` already running

Answer (score 0):

finish() just hides the activity but not killed immediately.
And makes it available for killing at later when os will need some memory to run other apps or processes.

Comment: I think, what you describe here is behavior of pausing the activity, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess Android allows you to save some data even after finish(). I think cancelling could also hurt the thread. In your case you could use return; to stop the code from executing.