# Stop service immediately when device is locked

Tags: android

I want to stop a service immediately when user press the power button. Unfortunately when i press power button, my service still runs for some seconds. Is it possible to stop service without waiting?

Comment: How are you stopping the service? Also is the service supposed to run in the background? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679278/why-is-finish-not-quitting-processing-immediately) but not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: i dont stop the service... system does it automatically

Answer (score 1):

You may want to register BroadcastReceiver  for "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" event, then call

```
stopService(Intent service);
```

method.

Comment: can u give me an exaample?